# calling plugin's controller from AppController in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I have written a plugin for CakePHP 3.4.*.

This plugin will check for Database configuration has been set or not, if not then It you move user through a GUI interface to setup database configuration just like wordpress.

The plugin is working perfectly, but it has to be loaded manually by visiting url of the plugin

```
http://example.com/installer/install
```

where `installer` is the plugin name which is calling `InstallController` class inside `plugins/Installer/src/Controller/` directory

Now what I want to check it automatically and redirect user to the Installation interface if database connection couldn't be established.

For that I have written a function inside `InstallController` of plugin's controller

```
public function installationCheck() {
    $db = ConnectionManager::get('default');

    if(!$db->connect()) {
        if(Configure::read('Database.installed') == true) {
            $this->Flash->error(__("Database connection couldn't be established. Please, re-configure it to start the application"));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__("Please configure your database settings for working of your application"));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Now the Question.**

**What is the easiest way to call this method from `/app/src/Controller/AppController.php` file of the main application?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, you don't!

Shared controller logic belongs either in `AppController` itself, a [Component](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html) or a [Trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). The `AppController` should never being accessing methods defined in other controllers, these shouldn't be made accessible to it.

For what you're doing you probably want to do this in a component that you can load via your `AppController` or the relevant controller.

So your component would look something like:-

```
<?php
namespace Installer\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;

class InstallComponent extends Component
{
    public function installationCheck()
    {
        // Method's logic
    }
}
```

Which you would then load in the relevant controller:-

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Installer.Install');
}
```

Then you can use the component's method from the controller like:-

```
$this->Install->installationCheck();
```

Comment: Thanks, implemented in my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should not Do that!

If you need to access another controller I recommend you to move that functionality to a [Component](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html), that are packages of logic that are shared between controllers.